# "Can't find" NS*Types (eg. NSFileManager or NSUrl) in Xamarin Forms project

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I get "Not Found" errors in Xamarin Forms with things like NSFileManager and NSUrl. These are my imports of my class where I'm getting these errors:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using DrinkUp.Controls;
using DrinkUp.iOS.Renderers;
using MediaPlayer;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
```

And the class which I'm using is located in DrinkUp.iOS.
Whenever and wherever I type something with the NS prefix it says that it could not find the object. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's my full class

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using DrinkUp.Controls;
using DrinkUp.iOS.Renderers;
using MediaPlayer;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Video), typeof(VideoRenderer))]
namespace DrinkUp.iOS.Renderers
{
public class VideoRenderer : ViewRenderer<Video, UIView>
{
MPMoviePlayerController videoPlayer;
object notification = null;

    void InitVideoPlayer()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, Element.Source);

        if (!NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists(path)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Video not exist");
            videoPlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController();
            videoPlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;
            videoPlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill;
            videoPlayer.RepeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One;
            videoPlayer.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            SetNativeControl(videoPlayer.View);
            return;
        }

        // Load the video from the app bundle.
        NSUrl videoURL = new NUrl(path, false);

        // Create and configure the movie player.
        videoPlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController(videoURL);

        videoPlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;
        videoPlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill;
        videoPlayer.RepeatMode = Element.Loop ? MPMovieRepeatMode.One : MPMovieRepeatMode.None;
        videoPlayer.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        foreach (UIView subView in videoPlayer.View.Subviews) {
            subView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        }

        videoPlayer.PrepareToPlay();
        SetNativeControl(videoPlayer.View);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "Forms" doesn't seem to be the appropriate namespace for non-graphical NS* types. See "Foundation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment worked, I had to get the NS types from Foundation.
Like Foundation.NSUrl etc. This fixed my problem.